# DOM elements don't get refreshed in pageinit/pageshow event after navigating using $.mobile.changePage with reloadPage=true

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have got two html pages each containing JQM page. If I move from Page1 to Page2 (by clicking the button in the example using **$.mobile.changePage** with **reloadPage=true**) and then move back to Page1 then assigning any value to txt1 textbox (inside the pageshow event) doesn't work - textbox remains BLANK. However in the **second trip** (i.e. Page1->Page2->Page1 using button click) it works. Code example is here:

## Page1.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Page-1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="page_1" data-theme="a" data-url="/JqmSimpleApp/Page1.htm">
            <div data-role="header" class="header_bar">
                Page-1 Header
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" class="investor-centre">
                Page-1 CONTENT
                <br/>
                <a id="btnMoveToPage2" href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Move to Page-2</a>
                <input type="text" id="txt1"/>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" data-position="fixed">
                Page-1 Footer
            </div>
            <!--################### Page specific Script Section #############################  --> 
            <!--NOTE: The reason it's been put under the data-role="page" section is that when a page is been loaded using Ajax call JQM only loads the content within data-role="page" section. --> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('body').off('pageinit', "#page_1").on('pageinit', "#page_1", function () {
                    alert('Page-1 INIT');
                    $("body").off("click", "#btnMoveToPage2").on("click", "#btnMoveToPage2", function () {
                        $.mobile.changePage("Page2.htm", { reloadPage: true });
                    });

                $("body").off("click", "#btnShow").on("click", "#btnShow", function () {
                    var myDate = new Date();
                    $("#txt1").val(myDate);
                    alert('Clicked');
                });

                });

                $('body').off('pageshow', "#page_1").on('pageshow', "#page_1", function () {
                    alert('Page-1 SHOW');
                    var myDate = new Date();
                    $("#txt1").val(myDate); //*** PROBLEM HERE - Doesn't show any value in the 1st round trip.****\\\
                    alert('txt1 value: ' + $("#txt1").val());// STRANGE!! When I read from txt1 text box it ALWAYS shows value
                });
            </script>            
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

## Page2.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page-2</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="page_2" data-theme="c" data-url="/JqmSimpleApp/Page2.htm">
            <div data-role="header" class="header_bar">
                Page-2 Header
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" class="investor-centre">
                Page-2 CONTENT
                <br/>
                <a id="btnMoveToPage1" href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Move to Page-1</a>
                <input type="text" id="txt2"/>                
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" data-position="fixed">
                Page-2 Footer
            </div>

            <!--################### Page specific Script Section #############################  --> 

            <!--NOTE: The reason it's been put under the data-role="page" section is that when a page is been loaded using Ajax call JQM only loads the content within data-role="page" section. --> 

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('body').off('pageinit', "#page_2").on('pageinit', "#page_2", function () {
                    alert('Page-2 INIT');
                    $("body").off("click", "#btnMoveToPage1").on("click", "#btnMoveToPage1", function () {
                        $.mobile.changePage("Page1.htm", { reloadPage: true });
                    });
                });

                $('body').off('pageshow', "#page_2").on('pageshow', "#page_2", function () {
                    alert('Page-2 SHOW');
                    var myDate = new Date();
                    $("#txt2").val(myDate);
                });
            </script>            
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that I'm trying to assign a value to an input element txt1 using $("#txt1").val(myDate) inside pageshow event in Page1. Textbox remains blank, **however if I read value from that textbox and display in an alert I can see the value in the alert box**. Do I have to refresh the UI somehow or am I using wrong event to access that element?

**Further investigation:**

Later on I have tried with one addition page (index.htm) from where I move to Page1 then Page2 and then round trip. So index.htm->Page1.htm->Page2.htm->Page1.htm and this time NO PROBLEM. So it means the problem with the very first page loaded through HTTP. As the subsequent pages being loaded using AJAX ($.mobile.changePage with reloadPage=true) they work fine. I have to say this is a bug in JQM. Is there any work aound for this?

Here is my index page:

## index.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page-1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
        <div data-role="page" id="page_1" data-theme="a" data-url="/JqmSimpleApp/Page1.htm">
            <div data-role="header" class="header_bar">
                Page-1 Header
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" class="investor-centre">
                Page-1 CONTENT
                <br/>
                <a id="btnMoveToPage2" href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Move to Page-2</a>
                <input type="text" id="txt1"/>

                <a id="btnShow" href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Show</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" data-position="fixed">
                Page-1 Footer
            </div>
            <!--################### Page specific Script Section #############################  --> 
            <!--NOTE: The reason it's been put under the data-role="page" section is that when a page is been loaded using Ajax call JQM only loads the content within data-role="page" section. --> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('body').off('pageinit', "#page_1").on('pageinit', "#page_1", function () {

                    //alert('Page-1 INIT');
                    $("body").off("click", "#btnMoveToPage2").on("click", "#btnMoveToPage2", function () {
                        $.mobile.changePage("Page2.htm", { reloadPage: true });
                    });

                    $("body").off("click", "#btnShow").on("click", "#btnShow", function () {
                        var myDate = new Date();
                        $("#txt1").val(myDate);
                        alert('Clicked');
                    });
                });

                $(document).off('pageshow', '#page_1').on('pageshow', "#page_1", function (event) {
                    //alert('Page-1 SHOW - ' + $("#txt1").length);
                    $("#txt1").val('');
                    var myDate = new Date();
                    $("#txt1").val(myDate); //*** PROBLEM HERE - Doesn't show any value in the 1st round trip.****\\\
                    alert('txt1 value: ' + $("#txt1").val()); // STRANGE!! When I read from txt1 text box it ALWAYS shows value

                });

            </script>            

        </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you wrap `click` event inside `pageinit`? take `click` events outside `pageinit`, and try again. `pageinit` fires only one time, once the page is inserted into DOM.

Comment: Hi Omar, thanks for your reply. Click event is not a problem for me. It fires as expected. I want to show current date time everytime I visit the page. Thats why I'm using pageshow event which suppose to execute everytime i visit the page but its not doing in the first round trip but does when the page loads first time and in the second round trip.

Comment: Use unique id `#txt1` and `#txt2`. Also, `$(document).on('pageshow', '#page_1', function () { your code });`

Comment: I'm already using unique id (pls see in the example) and have tried $(document).on('pageshow'... but no luck :-(

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/rumWE/

Comment: No luck yet. I have to use physical pages. However I have found another interesting thing which I have replicated in Page1 (edited) example. I have added an alert box (right after assigning value to txt1) which reads value from txt1. Very strangely I can see the value in the alert box but txt1 remains blank. Is it something to do with page/txt1 refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding **$.mobile.activePage** as jquery selector context (second parameter) solves the problem.

```
$("#txt1", $.mobile.activePage).val(myDate);
```

Comment: Any idea why this fixed the problem? I just did this and it worked.